# Laravel 5 : is it need to create new migration everytime while changes any column structure?

Tags: laravel

I seen in laravel documentation that whenever i append new column in existing table at that time i need to create 
`php artisan make:migration append_tablename`

it is fine this level. but next time i need to update any column structure of same table then i need to create new migration or i can add this below code in second migration file which i already used for append new column ?

```
$table->string('name', 50)->change();
```

any idea please share.

Comment: Do you wish to change any existing column? Yes you can change it to last migration file. Remember that it'll undo using `php artisan migrate:rollback` and once push that code to prod, you/other developer cannot change it to previous one!

Answer (score 2):

Migrations only run once, so adjusting an already-ran migration won't do you any good. During development, you can keep tweaking one and run `php artisan migrate:rollback` to undo it and re-run it repeatedly until you get it right, but once you a) push to production or b) push it somewhere other developers may run it you shouldn't touch the migration any more.

Comment: what happen  if i already applied multiple migration after append new column, it mean to say after some day i want to do change structure  then this rollback is work well or it will only rollback last migration only ?

Answer (score 0):

Every migration should be independent.

Unless you are explicitly refactoring for it to be more compact (If you know that you want to deploy a cleaner version in production and it won't mess with other developers work). In which case you should probably add it to your initial table creation.

It is your database history and versioning. Which allow's you to rollback to any previous state.